# How to modify a feature installation in Wix with custom property

Tags: wix, wix3.11

Wix newbie - but I expect that is apparent.
I am using a modified version of the WixUI FeatureTree extension for an application that basically just copies files to specific directories.  The installation wants to copy or remove based on a checkbox selection.

[image: CustomizeDlg Window customized]

I have a feature for each installation package.  I'm creating properties for each option and using them as a condition for each feature, changing the feature level to 1 or 0.

```
    <!--Features for REVIT v2020-->
    <Feature Id="Product2020" Title="Performance Seating v2020" Level="1">
        <Condition Level="1">
            <![CDATA[REVIT2020SELECTED = "Selected"]]>
        </Condition>

        <Condition Level="0">
            <![CDATA[REVIT2020SELECTED <> "Selected"]]>
        </Condition>

        <!--Reference to Components.wxs component list hard coded-->
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="2020Components" />

    </Feature>
```

In the UI, I set the state of the property at the checkbox.

```
                <Control Id="cbRevit2020"
                     Type="CheckBox"
                     Property="REVIT2020SELECTED"
                     X="50"
                     Y="110"
                     Height="10"
                     Width="150"
                     CheckBoxValue="Selected"
                     Text="Revit 2020"/>
```

The installation runs as expected on first run - features are installed based on the checkbox selection.  Uninstall also works fine.  Modify, however, does nothing regardless of checkbox state. I haven't changed anything in the FeatureTree.wxs custom file other than referencing my custom CustomizeDlg file.

I found reference to the issue (I think) here - https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/  However, it's over 10 years old and seems overly complex for what I need to do.

Does someone have a better approach?

BTW - yes, I know this is solvable simply by using the FeatureTree element.  This is purely a personal preference, as I'm not a fan of that user interface in this application.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved after quite a bit of searching and am posting in case it helps anyone else.

This article describes my desire and offers a good description of what is going on.  https://www.joyofsetup.com/2007/05/30/feature-conditions-and-ui/

I removed the condition from the feature and moved it into the dialog as a publish event under the Next button control.

```
<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="248" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)">
<Subscribe Event="SelectionNoItems" Attribute="Enabled" />
<Publish Event="AddLocal" Value="ALL">1</Publish>
<Publish Event="Remove" Value="PRODUCT2020">NOT REVIT2020SELECTED</Publish>
<Publish Event="Remove" Value="PRODUCT2021">NOT REVIT2021SELECTED</Publish>
<Publish Event="Remove" Value="PRODUCT2022">NOT REVIT2022SELECTED</Publish>
<Publish Event="Remove" Value="PRODUCTFAMILIES">NOT FAMILIESSELECTED</Publish>
```

I preset selections in the dialog based on install condition.

```
    <SetProperty Id="REVIT2020SELECTED" 
                 After="MigrateFeatureStates" 
                 Value="Selected">
        <![CDATA[REVIT2020INSTALLED AND (NOT Installed OR NOT !PRODUCT2020=2)]]>
    </SetProperty>
```